# Hot to solve: VBA Copy Values only 1004 Error?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have an excel protected sheet that is being used by several users and I've found that they sometimes Copy&Paste info from a different application that Blocks the pasted cells (while changing other formats as well).

The solution that I've found is using a macro in ThisWorkbook that forces the Copy as Value.
As I don't have that much experience in VBA, I've decided to use some available code in the internet.
The problem is that the marco works just fine in my Excel, but not in an older version of Excel (where I need it to work...).

I'm getting the 1004 Error. From what I've read so far I believe this happens because the info in the Clipboard dissappears when I run the macro.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Below is the code that I'm using:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim UndoString As String, srce As Range
    On Error GoTo err_handler    
    UndoString = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
    If Left(UndoString, 5) <> "Paste" And UndoString <> "Auto Fill" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    If UndoString = "Auto Fill" Then
        Set srce = Selection
        srce.Copy
        Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.SendKeys "{ESC}"
        Union(Target, srce).Select
    Else
        Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
err_handler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You have no `.Copy` on your `Else` statement, just the `.PasteSepcial`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, two lines have been inserted

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim UndoString As String, srce As Range
    On Error GoTo err_handler    
    UndoString = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
    If Left(UndoString, 5) <> "Paste" And UndoString <> "Auto Fill" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    If UndoString = "Auto Fill" Then
        Set srce = Selection
        srce.Copy
        Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.SendKeys "{ESC}"
        Union(Target, srce).Select
    Else
        Selection.Copy 'This line has been inserted
        Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 'This line has been inserted
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
err_handler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It looks as though that section of the code (`Else` etc.) only applies if they used Paste but not AutoFill.

I don't see the merit of using the `If` block to distinguish between `UndoString = "Auto Fill"` and any other result, which based on an earlier `If` block can only include a situation where the last undoable action name started with (or was) `Paste`. Don't you want to do the same thing to both `Auto Fill` and `Paste`?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.
I've added the 2 lines that you've suggested and the runtime error 1004 has indeed disappeared. But the nothing is pasted into the cell. But I've checked and info is still in the clipboard (I've tested using Application.ClipboardFormats(1))
Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to work out which lines and if blocks are invoked. I would set a breakpoint on the 4th line (beginning `UndoString`) using F9, then run it till it pauses there. Then step through each line using the F8 key and work out a) does it go into the first if block (beginning `If Left`), b) does it go into the second if block (beginning `If UndoString = "Auto Fill" Then`), c) does it go into the `else` statement.

Comment: It is going to the `Else` of the 2nd `If`, as it should, but the `Target.PasteSpecial` doesn't seem to do anything. Not sure why. I even removed this 2nd `If` block as suggested above for the sake of simplicity, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: What if you change `Target` to `Selection`? i.e. `Selection.PasteSpecial`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately still doesn't work.

Comment: Imagine I'm trying to copy the number 123 into a cell that already contains the number 999. What's happening is that before the `Application.Undo` both the `Target` and the `Selection` = to 123 (as should be), but after the `Application.Undo` they both change to 999. So I'm guessing that when I reach the line `Target.PasteSpecial` or `Selection.PasteSpecial` it just pastes the 999 instead of the 123...

Comment: `Target` and `Selection` are cell range references. `Target` is the cell/s currently being changed (or pasted into). `Selection` is the cell/s currently selected. Both `Target.PasteSpecial` and `Selection.PasteSpecial` will use the clipboard contents to determine WHAT is pasted (e.g. 123 or 999). The `Target` or `Selection` is about WHERE it is pasted.